# Issues with indexOf and lastIndexOf on substring - Get Part of URL from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, substring, indexof

I'm having a few issues breaking apart a string in the way I want. I have a url like this:

```
http://SomeAddress.whatever:portWhatever/someDirectory/TARGETME/page.html
```

I'm trying to get the TARGETME portion on the string, using substring and indexOf instead of regex. This is the function I'm working with now:

```
 function lastPartofURL() {
    // Finding Url of Last Page, to hide Error Login Information
    var url = window.location;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    alert(filename);
}
```

However, when I wrote this I was targeting the 'page.html' part, so that's what it returns, but I'm having trouble reconfiguring this to do what I want it to do now.

If possible, I would like it to originate from the beginning of the string rather than the end, as there should always be a url and then one directory before what I'm trying to target, but I'm interested in both solutions.

Here is a regex that does something similar, but it's not secure (according to JSLint), and therefore I wouldn't mind replacing it with something more functional.

```
 /^.*\/.*\/TARGETME\/page.html.*/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already answered by others, `.split()` is good for your case however assuming you mean to return "the part before last" of the URL (e.g. return "TARGETME" for `http://SomeAddress.whatever:portWhatever/dirA/DirB/TARGETME/page.html` as well) then you can't use fixed number but rather take the item before last of the array:

```
function BeforeLastPartofURL() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var parts = url.split("/");
    var beforeLast = parts[parts.length - 2]; //keep in mind that since array starts with 0, last part is [length - 1]
    alert(beforeLast);
    return beforeLast;
}
```

Comment: This is great! This will make a more robust solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easier with `string.split()`...

```
function getPath() {
    var url = window.location;
    var path = url.split("/")[4];
    alert(path);
    return path;
}
```

I only suggest this method since you say you will always know the format of the URL.

Comment: This is a great solution! However, like you acknowledged, it's dependent on the url always being the same, so it's limited to my scope as of now. Very short and succinct now!

Answer (score 1):

```
 function lastPartofURL() {
    // Finding Url of Last Page, to hide Error Login Information
    var url = window.location;
    var arr = url.split('/');

    alert(arr[4]);
 }
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZetvR/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    function lastPartofURL() {
    // Finding Url of Last Page, to hide Error Login Information
    var url = window.location;
    var sIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
    var dIndex = url.lastIndexOf('.', sIndex);
    if (dotIndex == -1)
    {
        filename = url.substring(sIndex + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        filename = url.substring(sIndex + 1, dIndex);
    }

    alert(filename);
}
```